# $location.path is not redirecting the document as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple program where I am trying to load a page in a  using a dropdown menu. But for some reason, the $location.path is not working.

Here is my code.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div>
        <div>
        <div ng-controller="RouteController">
            <select ng-model="opt.selector" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">

            </select>
            <button ng-click="selectFn()">Go</button>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/one', {
        templateUrl: '1.html',
        //controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/two', {
        templateUrl: '2.html',
        //controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index.html'
      });
  }]);

    sampleApp.controller('RouteController', function($scope){

        $scope.options=[
            {label: '1', url:'#one'},
            {label: '2', url:'#two'}  

        ];
        $scope.selectFn = function($locationProvider){

            $location.path($scope.opt.selector.url));

        }

    });
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?
I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: $location is not defined
    at Object.$scope.selectFn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `$location` into your controller so that the singleton can be used inside the controller. You are (I think trying to inject it int a function in your controller?) which won't work the way you are using it right now. If you want to do it the way you are doing right now:

```
    sampleApp.controller('RouteController',  function($scope, $location){

        $scope.options=[
            {label: '1', url:'#one'},
            {label: '2', url:'#two'}  

        ];
        $scope.selectFn = function(){

            $location.path($scope.opt.selector.url));

        }

    });
```

Although I highly recommend using the `$window` service to redirect

Comment: Not to sound presumptuous since I can see you're not heavy StackOverflow user, but please accept answers on your questions (by clicking the grey checkmark) if they have helped you as a courtesy on StackOverflow and to help any future people who have the same problem as you. But just wondering, is there a reason you haven't accepted an answer on any of your other questions?